# Firebase query: Why is child_added called before the value query in the following code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a schema in Firebase that looks like this:

```
messages/
  $groupId/
    $messageId/
      message: 'Sample Message'
      createdBy: 'userID'
      createdAt: 1513337977055
```

Then I have the following queries executed consecutively in my code:

```
// Get a specific message
ref.child('messages/$groupId/$messageId')
  .once('value')
  .then(snap => console.log('value', snap.val()))

// Start new message listener
ref.child('messages/$groupId')
  .orderByKey()
  .limitToLast(1)
  .on('child_added', snap => console.log('child_added', snap.val()))
```

I'm wondering why `child_added` gets called twice here, the first one being similar to the value returned by the `once('value')` query.

Here's what the console displays:

```
child_added { message: 'Hello', createdAt: 1513337977055, createdBy: 'userId' }
value { message: 'Hello', createdAt: 1513337977055, createdBy: 'userId' }
child_added { message: 'Another message', createdAt: 1513337977066, createdBy: 'userId2' }
```

Note that I'm not adding new entries to Firebase here. Just querying.

EDIT: Here is a fiddle link demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dspLwvc3/2/

Comment: This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. ... Its mean you have two data for now and fire twice. If you have 3 then will fire 3 for each.  Check link for more info. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events

Comment: That's correct. But the problem is I am not adding any new entries. I'm just querying. So why would a child_added trigger twice on first load even if I set `limitToLast(1)`?

Comment: This is not the subject. Issue is, at first trigger for each item and console it. Then if you add a record, then trigger one more. See the documentation above.

Comment: I expect `child_added` to only trigger once though on first load.

Comment: Than use `the on('value', snap => {})` with `limitToLast(1)` filter, that will be what you need I think. Will fire ones at each changes. And when you sort the list with timestamp, you will get last record.

Comment: Will probably apply your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: It really looks like there is new data being added under `messages/$groupId`. By definition that will result in a `child_added` event on that location, which results in your listener being called.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there is no new data being added. I created a fiddle demonstrating this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dspLwvc3/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*firebase here*

You've uncovered a quite interesting edge case there. The behavior you're seeing is expected from how the system operates. But I think we can all agree that it's far from intuitive. :-/

It's essentially a race condition, combined with Firebase's guarantees about what it will and won't fire and when it fires events.

Essentially what happens is this:

```
    Client                  Server
      |                       |
   (1)|  --once('value'---->  |
      |                       |
   (2)|  -on('child_added'->  |
      |                       |
      |           .           |
      |           .           |
      |           .           |
      |                       |
      |         value         |
   (3)|  <------------------- |
      |                       |
      |         child         |
   (4)|  <------------------- |
      |                       |
```

There are 4 key moments in there:

1. You attach a `once('value')` listener for `/messages/message1`. The client sends the request to the server and waits.
2. You attach a `on(-child_added` listener for the last-known key of `/messages`. The client sends the request to the server and waits.
3. The response to the first request comes back from the server. At this stage there are two listeners. The `once('value` listener is clear, so it fires and is removed. But at this point `/messages/message1` is also the last-known key of `/messages`, so the client fires that `child_added` listener too.
4. The response with `/messages/message3` comes back from the server. There is only one listener left and it requested to hear about the last message, so it fires. Note that if you'd also have a listener for `child_removed`, it would fore for `/messages/message1` at this point.

As I said, it's not very intuitive. But from the system's perspective it is the correct behavior. That means that you don't want this behavior, you will need to use the API in a different way. The simplest one with your current code would be to move attaching the `child_added` listener *into* the `once('value'` callback:

```
ref.child('messages/$groupId/$messageId')
  .once('value')
  .then(snap => {
    console.log('value', snap.val()))

  // Start new message listener
  ref.child('messages/$groupId')
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(1)
    .on('child_added', snap => console.log('child_added', snap.val()))
  })
```

This works because, by the time the `child_added` listener is attached, the `/messages/message1` snapshot has already been flushed from the client's cache.

Update (2018-01-07): another developer encountered this behavior and had a hard time maintaining the order of children. So I wrote up a bit more how this behavior (while unexpected) still maintains the correct order of the children. For more, see my answer here: [Firebase caching ruins order of retrieved children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139076/firebase-caching-ruins-order-of-retrieved-children/48140197#48140197)

Comment: oh wow, I can only imagine someone new to Firebase getting confused with this behavior. In large Firebase applications, this can be problematic because it's possible there will be several queries being called at the same time. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: I really believe there should be a side note somewhere in the Firebase docs about this particular issue though

Comment: Encountering this issue in June 2020. We encountered this issue in the React Native Firebase library (https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3940), would this solution suggest that this documentation is therefore incorrect. It seems no guarantees are provided at all? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-guarantees

Comment: See my linked answer in how to use the events to build a consistent internal state.