# Firebase caching ruins order of retrieved children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat application, and on the conversations/chats list, the last message of a chat is retrieved in order to show it just like in any other messenger app.

However, when the chat is opened, all messages of the chat are retrieved using `messagesDbRef.orderByChild("time").addChildEventListener(...)` and the `onChildAdded` callback is instantly called for the last message of the chat (the one retrieved on the chats list) which has the highest value for the `time` field, while all other messages are then retrieved from the database in the ascending order of the `time` field values.

In the example of messages labeled from 1 to 5, this causes them to be added to the RecyclerView in the order [5, 1, 2, 3, 4], with 5 being the last message.

However, when the chat is closed and opened again, the order is correct [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

How can I fix this? Is there a way to force reload all messages when the chat is opened?

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimal working example that reproduces the problem:

Data in realtime database:

```
testing: {
    abc123: {
        name: "first",
        time: 100
    },
    abc456: {
        name: "second",
        time: 200
    },
    abc789: {
        name: "third",
        time: 300
    }
}
```

Code:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("testing");

ref.child("abc789").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Stuff lastStuff = dataSnapshot.getValue(Stuff.class);
        Log.i("Testing", "retrived child " + lastStuff.name + " with time " + lastStuff.time);

        ref.orderByChild("time").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Stuff stuff = dataSnapshot.getValue(Stuff.class);
                Log.i("Testing", "name: " + stuff.name + ", time: " + stuff.time);
            }
            
            ...
});
```

This produces the output:

> I/Testing: retrived child third with time 300
>
> I/Testing: name: third, time: 300
>
> I/Testing: name: first, time: 100
>
> I/Testing: name: second, time: 200

**However**, I noticed that if I use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`, the problem is gone and the order is correct. I guess I just have a listener open somewhere in my application.

In any case, I don't think that the cached value should interfere with the order of retrieval later on.

Comment: I haven't seen ordering problems due to Firebase's caching in quite some time. Can you show the [minimal-but-complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated my answer with more information including the example.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can reproduce the behavior with that. I think you're seeing what another dev recently found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921039/firebase-query-why-is-child-added-called-before-the-value-query-in-the-followin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is caused by the fact that Firebase already has one of the children in memory indeed. I explained it recently in an answer to [Firebase query: Why is child_added called before the value query in the following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921039/firebase-query-why-is-child-added-called-before-the-value-query-in-the-followin).

But the order is maintained, as long as you use all the information that Firebase gives you. To show this I added some additional logging to your code:

```
ref.child("abc789").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Testing", "retrieved child " + dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() + " with time " + dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue());

        ref.orderByChild("time").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.i("Testing", "ChildAdded: key "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" name " + dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() + ", time " + dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue()+" previousKey "+s);
            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.i("Testing", "ChildChanged: key "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" name " + dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() + ", time " + dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue()+" previousKey "+s);
            }

            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i("Testing", "ChildRemoved: key "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" name " + dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() + ", time " + dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue());
            }

            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.i("Testing", "ChildMoved: key "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" name " + dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() + ", time " + dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue()+" previousKey "+s);
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.err.println("Listener was cancelled "+error.toString());
            }

        });

    }
```

So this now logs:

1. the key for each child snapshot
2. the previous key (called `s` in your code) that is passed
3. it's also logging each event, although in this test we only use `onChildAdded`

When you run this code it logs:

> 01-07 10:10:23.859 3706-3706/? I/Testing: retrieved child third with time 300
>
> 01-07 10:10:23.869 3706-3706/? I/Testing: ChildAdded: key abc789 name third, time 300 previousKey null
>
> 01-07 10:10:23.932 3706-3706/? I/Testing: ChildAdded: key abc123 name first, time 100 previousKey null
>
> 01-07 10:10:23.933 3706-3706/? I/Testing: ChildAdded: key abc456 name second, time 200 previousKey abc123

Using the `previousKey`/`s` argument is key in this case, which becomes clear if we replay how you build a UI/list out of this information. I recommend that you refer to the [reference documentation for `onChildAdded()` before going through these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html#onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot, java.lang.String)):

1. You start with an empty list.
2. You receive the child `abc789`, which you add to the list as its only element: `[abc789]`
3. You receive the child `abc123`. Since it doesn't have a previous key, you add it to the **start** of the list: `[abc123, abc789]`
4. You receive the child `abc456`, with previousKey `abc123`. When we insert this after `abc123` we get the final list: `[abc123, abc456, abc789]`

So while the order in which the `onChildAdded` calls happen is indeed somewhat surprising, the information passed into them allows you to build the correct UI/list for the children.

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't even think about checking out what the other parameter "s" represents. Though all this requires finding the child that has its id equal to s (existing children end up before abc789 in the list, while new children will end up after it), which is not the best solution but good enough for my case.